# How can I create a new variable using 2 columns that satisfy certain conditions using RStudio

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I would like to create a column of infection status for individuals. In my dataset, Malaria_RDT is a Malaria diagnostic test and CCA_test is a Schistosomiasis diagnostic test.

I want my new variable of infection status to be either; ONLY malaria infection, ONLY Schistosomiasis infection, neither malaria OR schistosomiasis infection or both malaria AND schistosomiasis infection

My dataset is called co.inf

```
if Malaria_RDT==0 and CCA_test==0, then inf.st = 0;
if Malaria_RDT >0 and CCA_test==0, then inf.st = 1;
if Malaria_RDT==0 and CCA_test >0, then inf.st = 2; and
if Malaria_RDT >=1 and CCA_test >=1, then inf.st = 3
```

Comment: You can chain ifelse commands like so `ifelse(co.inf$Malaria_RDT == 0 & co.inf$CCA_test==0, co.inf$inf.st = 0, ifelse(co.inf$Malaria_RDT > 0 & co.inf$CCA_test==0, co.inf$inf.st = 1, ifelse(co.inf$Malaria_RDT == 0 & co.inf$CCA_test>0,  co.inf$inf.st = 2, co.inf$inf.st=3)`

Comment: Hi Tiago, can you put your R code with the dataset. In this way we could help you.

Comment: I have been able to work it out thanks to your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a use case for `dplyr::case_when()` :

```
co.inf %>%
  mutate(inf.st = case_when(Malariad_RDT == 0 & CC_test == 0 ~ 0,
                            Malariad_RDT > 0 & CC_test == 0 ~ 1,
                            Malariad_RDT == 0 & CC_test > 0 ~ 0,
                            Malariad_RDT >= 1 & CC_test >= 1 ~ 0
                            ))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
co.inf$inf.st <- if (co.inf$Malaria_RDT == 0 & co.inf$CCA_test == 0) {
  0
} else if (co.inf$Malaria_RDT > 0 & co.inf$CCA_test == 0) {
  1
} else if (co.inf$Malaria_RDT == 0 & co.inf$CCA_test > 0) {
  2
} else {
  3
}
```